# cakephp attach more belongsto

Tags: cakephp, plugins, model-binding, belongs-to

I have an model i want to check more plugins, if plugins loaded then attach models in plugin into man model. i using this method? But different result in model and action.
Is another method better than construct for binding more for plugin checking.

```
class Comment extends AppModel {

/**
 * @see Model::$belongsTo
 */
    public $belongsTo = array(
        'Content' => array(
            'className' => 'Content',
            'foreignKey' => 'object_id',
            'conditions' => array(
                'Comment.object_id = Content.id',
            )
        ),
    );

/**
 * @see Model::__construct
 */
    public function __construct($id = false, $table = null, $ds = null) {
        // parent
        parent::__construct($id, $table, $ds);

        // check for newsstudio
        if (CakePlugin::loaded('NewModel')) {
             $this->bindModel(
                array('belongsTo' => array(
                    'NewModel' => array(
                        'className' => 'NewModel.NewModel',
                        'foreignKey' => 'object_id',
                        'conditions' => array(
                            'Comment.object_id = NewModel.id',
                        )
                    )
                )
            ));
        }

        var_dump($this->belongsTo); // correct! NewModel added to blongsto
    }
}

// but in action during use. Plugin loaded but 
var_dump($this->Comment->belongsTo); // incorrect! just `Content` added
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering you are doing it in the __construct, you may as well just add it to the `$belongsTo` property before calling the parent which would save a few CPU cycles as you are not doing an additional method call.

```
class Comment extends AppModel {

/**
 * @see Model::$belongsTo
 */
    public $belongsTo = array(
        'Content' => array(
            'className' => 'Content',
            'foreignKey' => 'object_id',
            'conditions' => array(
                'Comment.object_id = Content.id',
            )
        ),
    );

/**
 * @see Model::__construct
 */
    public function __construct($id = false, $table = null, $ds = null) {
        // check for newsstudio
        if (CakePlugin::loaded('NewModel')) {
            $this->belongsTo['NewModel'] = array(
                        'className' => 'NewModel.NewModel',
                        'foreignKey' => 'object_id',
                        'conditions' => array(
                            'Comment.object_id = NewModel.id',
                        )
                    );
        }
        parent::__construct($id, $table, $ds);
    }
}
```